# Disable windows settings icon in windows magnifier view

Tags: java

I am looking for a way to disable the windows settings icon which is displayed in the task bar/view of windows magnifier application.

[image: here]

I intend to implement this in java. Any leads would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: you didn't attach an image?

Comment: this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyiAM.png)? You must edit the question to include that, not only its reference (including `![enter image description here][1]` in text)